# Angular routing with href does not work on android browser

Tags: android, angularjs, url-routing, href

I'm getting puzzled by this..
I have this piece of code:

`<a href=" #/products/{{product.id}}"  ng-click="customFunction()">`

Where product is an object with an 'id' element.
Where `customFunction` adds the product in a shopping cart

Both are combined because the route in the `href` element permits to access a new page where the added product is customizable.

The code and the routing is working fine cross browser except on mobile phone (android at least, both chrome and native browser). On android phone only the `ng-click` reacts on click. But i am still able to open the web page routed by `href` by pressing the link and opening in a new tab :oO

my routing looks like that (app.js):

```
    when('/products/:productId', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/store_composition.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            })
```

and in the main Ctrl is called the getProduct function:

```
  if ($routeParams.productId != null) {
    $scope.product = $scope.store.getProduct($routeParams.productId);
}
```

which access the `store.js` file here :

```
store.prototype.getProduct = function (id) {
for (var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
    if (this.products[i].id== id)
        return this.products[i];
}
return null;
```

}

And it works fine... Except on android!! but again the link exists if long pressed for new tab :s :s

Any idea?

Update: 
I am noticing that the URL in the navbar of android/chrome never changes. Contrarly of whats happening in regular browsers (an URL such as `app/index.html#/products/batavia400` is updated on top) 
But except for the route i have linked in my post every other routing in my app are working (with no url update just the same... :/)

SOLVED: 
I actually solved the problem by adding the

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

and its the `user-scalable=no`that made the trick. 
The screen was slightly, really slightly zoomed by default by android, and this was creating the conflict on user's touch on the div's link.
I guess if my web designing skills were better I wouldn't have had the problem ;)

Comment: *"But i am still able to open the web page routed by href by pressing the link and opening in a new tab"* - clicking on a link *should* navigate to the URL.  If you only want the `ng-click` action, remove the href?

Comment: I want both. Right now on android its like there are no href anyway. And again the code works on chrome/firefox/IE...

Comment: what does `customFunction()` contain and what is it for? Seems strange to need both `href` and `ng-click`

Comment: Hi, as i said the function adds an item in a cart. The Href redirects to a page where the cart's item can be furthermore customizable. I don't see why it would be strange, how else would you do it?

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation that guarantees the lifecycle of a *"both non-empty href and ng-click click"*. That shouldn't be a standard thing. I would just change location with router in the `customFunction`

Comment: found the trick with `user-scalable=no` thx for your help, post edited

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved the problem by adding the

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

and its the `user-scalable=no`that made the trick. 
The screen was slightly, really slightly zoomed by default by android, and this was creating the conflict on user's touching the div's link.